# Converting seconds in dd:hh:mm:ss [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently learning Python --version 3.4 and I have an issue while converting seconds in dd:hh:mm:ss.

If I only convert seconds into hh:mm:ss it's working but when I try with days for example with 86400 seconds it'll give me this:

```
./convert.py
Enter seconds: 86400
1 d 24 h 0 m 0 s
```

I'm not sure if I understand why it is doing this and I've been trying to fix this issue but I can't seem to find out how to do this properly.

```
s = int(input("Enter the seconds: "))

d = int(s / 60 / 60 / 24 % 365)

h = int(s / 60 / 60)   

m =int(s / 60 % 60)    

sec = int(s % 60)      

print(d,"d" ,h,"h" ,m,"m" ,sec,"sec")
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pythonfiddle.com/time-converter-seconds-to-ddhhmmss-format/

Comment: You're missing `%24` on the hour

Comment: `"{:0>8}".format(datetime.timedelta(seconds=666777)` from @marcell 's answer in the link I posted should solve the issue

Comment: check out [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod)